# Deleting a Linked List and printing it (GeeksForGeeks)

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

**My code:**

```
class Node():
    # defining attributes of node and constructor
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList():
    # defining the attribute
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printList(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("The LinkList is empty")
        else:
            temp1 = self.head
            while(temp1):
                print(temp1.data)
                temp1 = temp1.next

    def deleteLinkedList(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("The LinkedList is already empty")
        else:
            temp2 = self.head
            while(temp2.next!=None):
                current = temp2
                temp2 = temp2.next
                del current.data
            self.head = None
```

**My doubt:**

Is this code correct to delete a while link list?

**Why am I setting `self.head` to `None` after deleting the linked list?**

Because I want to print the content of the list using the following function:

```
def printList(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("The LinkList is empty")
        else:
            temp1 = self.head
            while(temp1):
                print(temp1.data)
                temp1 = temp1.next
```

Comment: You want to clear the contents on the linked list? All that would be required is `self.head = None`. `del current.data` on each node is not necessary.

Comment: I know, that what I thought but on GeeksForGeeks it says I need to delete the data of each node. But what about the next part of each node? It is also occupying the memory right?

Comment: Deleting every node one by one yourself would be necessary in a language where the programmer handles the memory themselves. Python has garbage collection. As soon as you have lost all reference to a piece of memory, python will erase it for you. So you definitely don't need to erase every node one by one.

Comment: I wouldn't follow [that guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-delete-a-linked-list/). I don't think "Shrikant13" is a good source. They're wrong, unless I'm missing something glaring, like they're reusing nodes for other purposes on later insertions. `del current.data` simply removes the `data` attribute from the node object, which is completely unnecessary to allow memory to be freed. Memory is automatically handled when it can no longer be referenced.

Comment: Exactly what I was wondering. It is understandable to delete each and every node one by one but in a language like Python or Java, it doesn't make any sense. Can someone post an answer here? I think it would be helpful for other fellow programmers who got confused because of that lousy guide.

Comment: For peace of mind, I've fixed the code and submitted the changes for review. Hopefully they're approved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that would really help out a lot of folks out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteLinkedList` is doing far more work than it needs to. `del current.data` removes the attribute from the `Node` object, but that is not necessary. You rarely want to delete attributes from objects.

The only thing that's necessary to clear the list and allow the memory to be freed is:

```
def deleteLinkedList(self):
    self.head = None
```

By setting `head` to `None`, you've ensured that the nodes it held previously can no longer be accessed (assuming you didn't store references to them elsewhere). Python will see this and automatically free the memory associated with the nodes.

---

If you were following [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-delete-a-linked-list/), I'd take it with a grain of salt. I can't see why they'd possibly recommend using `del` there, unless they had a plan to reuse the node structures later for later insertions; but that's unlikely, and likely wouldn't be beneficial anyways since `Node`s are so cheap to allocate.